# Move File to a Different Folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

In Google Sheets i have 2 columns:
A)"Google Drive file IDs"
B)"New File Paths".

I like a script that could move the file to the path according to the path in the cell. And could create the folder if the folder doesn't exist.

I found this script "[Move File to a Different Folder in Google Drive](https://www.labnol.org/code/20201-move-file-to-another-folder)" but would need help getting it to work in Sheets

Comment: what do you mean by New File Paths ? would that be a folder id for example?

Comment: Great idea! yes, i could use a Folder ID instead

Comment: Awesome Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need two functions but you only need to run one of them; that is the **main** function.

### Explanation:

Function **fileMover** will take care of the moving of the files:

```
function fileMover(id,targetFolderId,parentFolderId) {

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
    try {
      DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file);}
    
    catch(e){
      const parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
      const newFolder=parentFolder.createFolder(file.getName() + " folder");
      DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder.getId()).addFile(file);    
    }
}
```

And the function **main** will iterate through the columns and execute **fileMover** for every row in your file:

```
function main () {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const parentFolderId = 'parentfoldeidhere'; 
  const file_ids = sh.getRange("A2:A"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);
  const folder_ids = sh.getRange("B2:B"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < file_ids.length ; i++){
  fileMover(file_ids[i],folder_ids[i],parentFolderId)
  }
}
```

### Important information:

As you can see in the **main** function, there is a variable **parentFolderId**. This folder is used as a **placeholder** for all the new folders that are being created when **Column B** (Folder_ID) **does not** provide a correct id. This is a better practice to keep your files organized within one "parent" folder.

Here is the structure of my spreadsheet file. **Column A** provides a list of the IDs of the files you want to move. And **Column B** provides a list of the folder IDs that you want to move the files in the same rows. If **Column B** provides a wrong folder ID, then a new folder will be created in the parent folder (adjust parent folder id in the **main** function). The new folder will have the name: `nameofthefile + " folder"`, but this can also be adjusted in line: `file.getName() + " folder"` of the `fileMover` function. Also, feel free to adjust the name of the sheet, in my case *Sheet1*.

[image: example]

Comment: Tks for the solution. Does the account that excecutes this code need to be the OWNER of the file and/or destination folder? Or they can simply have edit access for both?